# How to change to interval of x ticks in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I make xticks of a plot in specific frequency? Here is my code:

```
# read data
df = pd.read_csv("newData/000001.csv")
df1 = df.loc[df['seqNo'] == 48]
df1 = df1.sort_values(by = 'date')
df1['date'] = df1['date'].astype(str)
# show plot
plt.plot(df1['date'], df1['close'], 'yellow', label = 'close')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("date")
plt.ylabel("value")
plt.title("000001")
plt.show()
```

and the plot, the x axis is too dense:
[image: image here]

and the part of the plot is :
[image]

The datatype of xaxis is string.

Comment: how to I show the a xtick every 10 or 100?

Comment: Do not use strings, if you want to plot dates, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47155569/difference-in-plotting-with-different-matplotlib-versions

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas default plotting:

```
df = pd.read_csv("newData/000001.csv")
df1 = df.loc[df['seqNo'] == 48]
df1 = df1.sort_values(by = 'date')

p = df.plot('date', 'close',  color='yellow', title="000001")
p.set_ylabel('value')
```

This does automatic spacing of the x ticks.

Example:

[image]