# Matplotlib key error with dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.6

I am trying to display some points using matplotlib, Although I can display them using print command but matplotlib gives error. The command that works is also there(commented).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

data = np.array([[-1,-1,'C1'],[-2,-1,'C1'],[-3,-2,'C1'],[1,1,'C2'],[2,1,'C2'],[3,2,'C2']])
query=[-2.5,-1.5]

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns =['x','y','Cat']
df

for i in range(6):
    if(df.ix[i]['Cat'] == 'C1'):
        plt.scatter(df.iloc[i]['x'], df.iloc[i]['y'], s=150, c='r') #error line
         #working linke below
         #print(df.iloc[i]['x'],df.iloc[i]['y'])
    else:
        plt.scatter(df.iloc[i]['x'], df.iloc[i]['y'], s=150, c='b')
        #working line below
        #print(df.iloc[i]['x'],df.iloc[i]['y'])
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

Thanks @Haleemur Ali for your help  I am able to run it now but still not fully functional. Not all points are showing not sure why?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

data = np.array([[-1,-1,'r'],[-2,-1,'r'],[-3,-2,'r'],[1,1,'b'],[2,1,'b'],[3,2,'b'],[-2.5,-1.5,'y']])
query=[-2.5,-1.5]

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns =['x','y','Cat']
print(df)

plt.scatter(df.x, df.y, s=150, c=df.Cat)
```

Graph generated

[image]

Comment: please post the full error message

Comment: In contrast to builtin `list` numpy arrays can only hold data of the same type. In your case `data` is cast to a string type (`<u21`) because of the strings on the second index. Matplotlib does not know how to plot non-numeric data; that's the problem here.

Answer (score 2):

If the numbers are strings, they are not recognized as numbers, hence they are plotted as categories, just as you would expect if you plotted `["apple", "banana", "cherry"]`. You would need to convert your data to floats:

```
df[['x', 'y']] = df[['x', 'y']].astype(float)
```

Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([[-1,-1,'r'],[-2,-1,'r'],[-3,-2,'r'],[1,1,'b'],
                 [2,1,'b'],[3,2,'b'],[-2.5,-1.5,'y']])

df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x','y','Cat'])
df[['x', 'y']] = df[['x', 'y']].astype(float)

plt.scatter(df.x, df.y, s=150, c=df.Cat)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: this is true! What I find interesting is that matplotlib correctly _inferred_ that the series passed to `scatter` were actually numeric, as you can see in my answer, but clearly not the case for the OP. BTW, I'm using the following versions on Windows Anaconda `pandas=0.20.3, matplotlib=2.0.2`. What versions are you using?

Comment: In matplotlib < 2.1, strings are converted to floats if possible, else an error is raised. In matplotlib >= 2.1 strings are interpreted as [categorical values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47155569/difference-in-plotting-with-different-matplotlib-versions).

Comment: I am using 2.1.0 version of matplotlib. That clears the confusion. But thing is even if matplotlib interpreted values as category why it did not displayed all the data. Thanks – ImportanceOfBeingErnest & – Haleemur Ali.

Answer (score 1):

Scatter plots aren't built by iterating through the data.

You can build the scatter plot for a particular category, like this:

```
plt.scatter(df.x[df.Cat=='C1'], df.y[df.Cat=='C1'], s=150, c='r')
```

[image: scatter plot for 1 category]

You can also create a scatter plot where each category gets a distinct colour

```
plt.scatter(df.x, df.y, s=150, c=df.Cat)
```

[image: scatter plot for all categories, where category determines point colour]