# pyplot plotting straight line always

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have this code to plot some data in python using matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[1,2,5]
y=[2,4,1]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

This this plots perfectly, here is the result :

[image: pyplot sample working]

In my another code, I have this value :

`x = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]`

`y = ['7065' '2604' '2003' '1939' '1746' '1578' '1472' '1414' '1320' '1288']`

Now, what I get is this :

[image: pyplot working gibberish]

Bar graph, is also same, here:

[image: bar graph error]

It always gives me a straight line, **why is that?**

Values are visible in *Python Shell*

Comment: Because your y values are strings so they are plotted as categories rather than floats.  Convert to floats if this is not what you wanted

Comment: Thanks worked , [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ1VD.png) is a snap

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was resolved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference in plotting with different matplotlib versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47155569/difference-in-plotting-with-different-matplotlib-versions)

Comment: This is some really bad default behaviour from a scripting language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote this :

`y = list(map(int, y))`

And the `str` list became `int` list.