# How to make python matplotlib bar begin at low number instead of high number?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been looking on the docs, SO and googling. Im new to matplotlib. My bar chart's bars are begining at the high number and moving to the low number. I want the 32.4 value on the left side to be at the top and have the bar reach to that and I want the 2.5 to be on the bottom and hve the far right bar reach to that. How does one change the bar chart to make this happen?

```
    outcomes_with_age = self.get_outcomes_with_age(objects)

    for key, value in outcomes_with_age.items():
        plt.figure(figsize=(9, 6))
        plt.suptitle(key)
        plt.ylabel('Y-axis')

        # plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 25))
        # plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
        names = []
        values = []
        for ref in value["ages"]:
            names.append(ref["age"])
            values.append(ref["rate"])
        plt.bar(names, values)
        break
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code used to generate this? We'll need something to go off of!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong, but since the y-values are not ordered whatsoever, it looks like a duplicate of
[Difference in plotting with different matplotlib versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47155569/difference-in-plotting-with-different-matplotlib-versions)

Short version: Your y values are read as strings! Cast them to float to (hopefully) normalize the plot.